# Assigning a text to an SVG element for copying to clipboard in browsers on Ctrl+C when it's selected by user

Tags: html, svg

I have the following HTML code:

```
<p>This is a <svg class="inline"><use href="#my-rect"></use></svg>!</p>
```

`my-rect` is a `<g>` element that looks like a box.

I want it to be copied as “This is a rect!” when the whole paragraph is selected in a browser and the user presses Ctrl+C.

How should I assign “rect” to the `svg` element? Setting a `title` doesn't work.